# Docker inside docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I Have a docker file for building a new image eg:ABC. Inside this dockerfile we are pulling another image from our AWS ECR as a base image, this setup is on AWS EKS. One of the pods will work like a Jenkins agent/slave machine, whenever I run this Jenkins job to build a new image. It takes more than 25min for a simple Docker image creation. A simple WORKDIR instruction takes more than 4min to execute.

I have Jenkins on AWS cloud, Slave machines are the pods in Kubernetes cluster, whenever there is a new job, slave machine/pod spins up and execute the Jenkins job and terminates auto,
I have a shell script to run in the Jenkins job, THis shell script has a command to build a new docker image ABC. The below Dockerfile takes ~20 min to build a new docker image.

I tried running the same dockerfile in my local machine, it took my ~4min to build the same image

Any help will be appreciated.

```
FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/menter-v5:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-jdk \
    && sudo mkdir /analyzer && sudo mkdir /usr/bin/mlrtapp/data

COPY deploy/backend2/analyzer.jar /analyzer/
COPY matlab/cluster.mat /usr/bin/mlrtapp/data/

VOLUME /usr/bin/mlrtapp/data
WORKDIR /usr/bin/mlrtapp

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 \
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin

ENTRYPOINT  java -jar /analyzer/analyzer.jar
```

Comment: I would start with a simple image build process profiling leveraging a default docker image build flag --profile. I assume the output could be accessible using Jenkins build console logs

Comment: Check if you allocate enough resources (maybe you set too aggressive resource limits) for those pods. Also consider kaniko builds - see if it makes a difference - see my recent tutorial here - https://worklifenotes.com/2022/01/04/jenkins-builds-with-kaniko-and-reliza-tutorial/

Comment: @taleodor wrt to resource allocation, I've 6GB of RAM and sufficient space is free during the entire Docker to build process, I don't think resource allocation would be a problem. I'll see the tutorial.